# Azure WebJob: In case of TimerTrigger, the operation is not logged to Application Insights as a request

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-webjobs

I found very strange thing: when a web job (WJ) is triggered by either Azure Service Bus or Even Hub event - the operation is logged to the Application Insights, but when a WJ is triggered by Timer - neither request nor exceptions are automatically logged to Application Insights.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Do you mean I should implement logging manually? Maybe there is a flag somewhere that dictates the platform to do that automatically (as it does for regular jobs)

Comment: Same problem here. When I run manually ("Run" button in Azure Portal), it logs fine, when is launched by time trigger, it doesn't. Also, when launched by time trigger, it doesn't know when the job have finished (shows "Running" permanently), which is incorrect and I suspect is the reason to don't flush the logs. I regret to have choosen Webjobs.